# Autofac not resolving injected property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I've an action filter attribute which has a property that needs to be injected by AutoFac.
Because it is an action filter attribute i can't use constructor injection.

**Property:**

```
  private readonly ISocialAppUnitOfWork _socialAppUnitOfWork;
```

**Resolve:**

```
  public SecurityActionFilter()
    {
          _socialAppUnitOfWork = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService <ISocialAppUnitOfWork>();
    }
```

**Config:**

```
   builder.RegisterType<SecurityActionFilter>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

   DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
```

After getting the service in the constructor the _socialAppUnitOfWork property remains null.

Why isn't it resolving my dependency?

Comment: Most probably because it's `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
  // Set this action filter for every controller and inject interface
  builder.Register(c => new SecurityActionFilter(c.Resolve<ISocialAppUnitOfWork>()))
            .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

  // Register all the action filters
  builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
builder.RegisterType().As().InstancePerHttpRequest();